# Adding postgresql repo to ubuntu 22.04 via ansible fails

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ansible, apt

From the following 2 tasks

```yaml
- name: Add key for Postgres repo
  apt_key: 
    url: https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
    state: present
  become: true

- name: Add Postgres repo to sources list
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ ubuntu-pgdg main'
    state: present
  become: true
```

the second one fails as follows:

```
TASK [common : Add Postgres repo to sources list] ******************************
fatal: [master-node]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "apt cache update failed"}
```

Why is that, given I am sudo-ing to execute it?

Comment: It looks like just a typo. Under the URL http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/ are no `ubuntu-pgdg`. Shouldn't it be something like `{{ YOUR_DISTRO }}-pgdg`?

Comment: you mean like `jammy-pgdg` ?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third field of an apt repository in the list file should be the codename of your distribution, not the distribution itself:

> The **sources.list** man page specifies this package source format:
>
> ```
> deb uri distribution [component1] [component2] [...]
> ```
>
> and gives an example:
>
> ```
> deb https://deb.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
> ```

> The **distribution** part (*stable* in this case) specifies a subdirectory in **$ARCHIVE_ROOT/dists**. It can contain additional slashes to specify subdirectories nested deeper, eg. *stable/updates*. **distribution** typically corresponds to **Suite** or **Codename** specified in the **Release** files.

*<sup>Source: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Overview</sup>*

Example of the *Release* file, containing the codename:

```bash
$ head -n 5 /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
```

---

If you don't want to hardcode it, this can be easily achieved with the help of [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html):

```yaml
- name: Add Postgres repo to sources list
  apt_repository:
    repo: >-
      deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ 
      {{ ansible_distribution_release }}-pgdg main
    state: present
  become: true
```

Which presuppose that you, at least, gather the minimal facts, e.g.:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_subset:
    - min
```

Or that you gather everything, i.e.: that you have no `gather_facts: false`, at the play level.